# Getting {"The process cannot access the file 'file' because it is being used by another process."} in # WPF App

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I've been working on this all day thus far and can not seem to find the cause of it...

I am building a basic application (my first one from scratch) where I can add names to list (stored in a .txt file) and then select a name from the list at random as a competition winner. On loading the application, the names stored in the txt file are shown in a textblock, and this is updated every time a name is added to the list without problems. The problem occurs when I am selecting a winner at random from the list. The first time I select one it works fine. It pops up a message box informing me of the winner, removes them from the list then updates the display. If I then click "select winner" again, it throws a System.IO exception saying the file is being used by another process. Here is what I have in the code now.

```
private void SelectWinner_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @"C:\CompWinner\Text\Entrants.txt";
        string path2 = @"C:\CompWinner\Text\Entrants2.txt";
        string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(allLines.ToString()))
        {
            string caption = "Error!";
            string messageBoxText = "There are currently no Entrants.\r\nPlease add some entrants to select a winner";
            MessageBoxButton messageBoxButton = MessageBoxButton.OK;
            MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, messageBoxButton);
        }
        else
        {
            var list = new List<string>();
            foreach (string line in allLines)
            {
                list.Add(line);
            }

            var r = new Random();
            int I = list.Count;
            int num = r.Next(I);

            var winner = list[num];

            string caption = "Winner!";
            string messageBoxText = "And the winner is:\r\n" + winner + "!\r\nCongratulations!";
            MessageBoxButton messageBoxButton = MessageBoxButton.OK;
            MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText, caption, messageBoxButton);

            list.Remove(winner);

            foreach (string item in list)
            {
                int attempts = 15;
                Exception cannotReadException = null;
                while (attempts > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path2))
                        {
                            string personName = item;
                            sw.WriteLine(personName);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        cannotReadException = exception;
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                        attempts--;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                if (cannotReadException != null)
                {
                    throw cannotReadException;
                }
            }
            ReplaceLists(sender, e);
        }    
    }
```

Even with the try/catch in there it still throws the exception the first time that cannotReadException != null

Really hoping someone can help me with this as its the last issue that I have with this application.

Comment: Does `ReplaceLists` do any IO on those files?

Comment: It does.. It does a File.Replace(path2, path1, backup);

Comment: I have resolved it by adding 
    {
    string personName = item;
    sw.WriteLine(personName);
    **sw.Close();**
    }